# Enabling form resizing

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-xe

I have a existing form where the resizing is disabled. I tried to change the property Border Style to bsSizeable and border icons to [biSystemMenu,biMinimize,biMaximize]. I am able to resize but the controls inside the form is not sized accordingly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We'd need to see the source-sample and many some of the .dfm file.

Comment: .Align is your friend

Comment: The alignment of your panels/other holding controls has been set to `alNone` set these to something more appropriate.

Comment: Also anchors will help with scaling according to your form size for some controls like panels, edits etc

Comment: I always try to set Anchors to my forms even if their border is set as `bsDialog` (which I try not to do much these days.) Some stuff align to top left, some to bottom right, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border style and icons control whether the *form* is resizable, but the controls on a form don't automatically move unless you've configured them to do so. Change their Align, Anchors, or Constraints properties, which all affect the size and position differently. You can also handle the form's OnResize event and arrange the controls however you want.

Comment: I changed the Anchors of the controls inside to [akLeft,akTop,akRight] everything works fine except check box where the check box is moving but the caption is not moving at all